# Run shell script though minicom for Android device

Tags: android, python-2.7, serial-port

Hi I wanted to run a python script through minicom connected to my Android device with a debug board. Please help me what could be the issue for the below console info, while running.

```
abcd@xyzz4:~$ sudo minicom -S flashimage.py
```

console

```
Welcome to minicom 2.5                                                    

OPTIONS: I18n                                                             
Compiled on May  2 2011, 10:05:24.                                        
Port /dev/ttyUSB0                                                         

Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys                                   

runscript: couldn't open "flashimage.py"                                  
runscript: couldn't open "flashimage.py"
```

Comment: i never tried this before but its obviously says that flashimage.py cannot be oppened. is it the correct folder ?

Comment: Yamen Nassif: Yes the path is set to correct folder